# Mocking Microsoft Graph API with in memory data

Tags: c#, mocking, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to unit test a method that returns a list of users with mocking by creating a list of users and passing them in to mock whether my repository methods returns that list of users.

At the moment I am getting an empty list. I am wondering if there's something missing when passing in the users in the test method.

I have a repository class with a method called GetUsersOnly() which makes a call to the Graph API like this:

```
    this.graphApi.GetUsersAsync().Result;
```

> This GetUsersAsync() is inside of the GraphAPI class that I wrote and makes a call to the Microsoft Graph API to get a list of users.

```
    public Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersAsync()
    { 
        return this.appClient.Users
            .Request(this.queryOptions)
            .Select(@$"
            Id,
            DisplayName,
            GivenName,
            Surname,
            Mail,
            OtherMails,
            CompanyName,"
            .OrderBy("DisplayName")
            .GetAsync();
    }

    
    public class B2CRepository : IB2CRepository
    {
    private readonly IGraphAPI graphApi;

    public B2CRepository(IGraphAPI graphApi)
    {
        this.graphApi = graphApi;
    }

    private List<User> GetUsersOnly()
    {
        var request = this.graphApi.GetUsersAsync().Result;
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        var graphUsers = request.ToList();

        do
        {
            users.AddRange(graphUsers);
            var nextPage = request.NextPageRequest;
            graphUsers = nextPage?.GetAsync().Result.ToList() ?? new List<User>();
        }
        while (graphUsers.Count > 0);
        return users;
    }
}
```

> Inside my test I am mocking the GraphAPI class:

```
var mockGraphAPI = new Mock<IGraphAPI>();
```

> Test method looks like this: my goal is simply to pass in some list of users and return that list from my repo method GetUsersOnly();

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetUserTest()
    {
        var users = new List<User>();
        var mockGraphAPI = new Mock<IGraphAPI>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var user = new User()
            {
                DisplayName = "TestUser2" + i,
            };

            users.Add(user);
        }

        var mockUserPageResult = new Mock<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage>();

        mockGraphAPI.Setup(api => 
        api.GetUsersAsync()).ReturnsAsync(mockUserPageResult.Object);
        mockUserPageResult.SetupGet(page => page.NextPageRequest);

        this.b2CRepository = new B2CRepository(mockGraphAPI.Object);
        var usersResult = this.b2CRepository.GetUsers();
        Assert.IsTrue(usersResult.Count() == 2);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if you wouldn't be better of wrapping your GraphAPI calls inside a custom service. Therefore, if you use dependency injection, you could inject the service you need for testing. However, if you really want to mock GraphAPI, this could help : https://dev.to/kenakamu/unit-testing-microsoft-graph-sdk-client-with-moq-library-4l24

Comment: this.b2CRepository.GetUsers(); There is no method GetUsers() in your B2CRepository class.     var users = new List<User>(); in GetUserTest(). Why do you create this list when it is never returned by any mock (SetupGet etc.)?

Comment: Here is the API to fetch the list of users with the filter capabilities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-5-use-filter-to-get-all-users-with-a-mail-that-ends-with-acontosocom-including-a-count-of-returned-objects-with-the-results-ordered-by-userprincipalname